# Ruby pack for complex data types

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers, binary-data, complex-numbers

I have read the documentation for Ruby Pack but I cannot find a way to pack Complex data types in ruby. What would be a good way to pack complex data types in ruby ?

Comment: Can you please include some code, so we know exactly what you're talking about? What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried so far? What is a "Complex data type"?

Comment: You can look at the  documentation for pack at  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html and you will find that you can pack integer and float but not complex data type. Example of array of complex data type is  array = [Complex(2,3)]

Comment: Okay, so we are indeed talking about ruby's built-in `Complex` class. Now, I repeat my question: What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried so far? `Array#pack` can only be used with arrays of floats, integers and strings - so we'll need to know a little more context to solve your actual problem.